# package apk using maven from command line 2021

Tags: java, android, maven

I want to package my Java application to Android APK.

Right now, I am able to package to JAR, and I want to continue to do so. I do this by:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

Figuring out how to package to APK is being tricky.
I have found [android maven plugin](https://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/index.html) and I have fullfilled all the requirements of this plugin (I am in a Linux environment).
It seems I am missing something on the configuration part in order to produce an APK.
I have comment out the parts of the `pom.xml` that I have tried, and that I still could not made it produce the APK.
To produce the APK I have run `mvn clean install` without any success.

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.brilhante.porkbunDdns</groupId>
<artifactId>porkbun-ddns-java</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<!--<packaging>apk</packaging>-->

<name>porkbun-ddns-java</name>
<url>http://gitlab.com/alexandre1985/porkbun-ddns-java/</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20210307</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
        <!--
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.brilhante.porkbunDdns.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <!--
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    -->
</build>
</project>
```

How should my `pom.xml` be in order to produce an APK? And what command to run?

Comment: If you want 'the 2021 way', you should use gradle.

Comment: To do it 2021 you should move the configuration for maven-assembly-plugin out of the pluginManagement part and bound it to the lifecycle afterwards you can simply do all in one via `mvn package`...

Comment: @dan1st I have tried unsuccessfully in gradle. @khmarbaise the thing is that I get always error, no matter what I try. Now I am getting the error `Invalid SDK: Platform/API level 26 not available`